# Is there a way to query Postgres data from DB2 (or vice versa) on an iSeries/as400?

Tags: postgresql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have a DB2 database and a Postgres database sitting side-by-side on our iSeries/as400. Is there a way to access the Postgres data from DB2 (or vice versa)?

It could be creative solutions rather than just a way to do cross-SQL statements, which I don't know is possible.

The reason we want to start using Postgres is the wealth of Node.js libraries out there that support it (and don't support DB2). For example, Strapi easily builds out a RDBMS in Postgres and automatically generates a GraphQL + REST API.

Comment: Search for "postgresql foreign data wrapper db2" and see if that works for you. If not, odbc/jdbc might be worth looking at

Comment: Look at this 2 links: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-server and https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ias?topic=SSHRBY/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/t0070302.html

Comment: @Nifriz thank you for the links. Is this something you've done successfully? Would you recommend it for production?

Comment: @sprite7 Sorry for the delay. I used it for an import from another DB and it worked